# How to Display horizonatal form submit buttons using lists

Tags: html, css

```
  <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <form name="frm1" action="" style="display:inline">
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="xxx">
                </li>
                <li>

                    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit">

                </li>
            </form>

            <li>
                <form name="frm2" action="" style="display:inline" >
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_reset" value="Reset">
                </form>
            </li>
  </ul>
```

I want the two buttons to be displayed horizontally.  i am trying to use lists rather than tables. What should i do to make the buttons displayed on the same line but as submit buttons of two forms.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. A list item cannot be a child of a form. (And you appear to be suffering from listitus, not everything needs to be in a list)

Comment: There are many things wrong with that snippet: Invalid HTML. Inline styles (bad practise, unless used just for asking the question - I doubt it in this case). Too much `ul` and `li`. And why are you making a separate `form` just to contain a Reset button?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:inline;` on `li`

Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWmnV/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly that you want to have the text input on the first line and the two buttons on the seccond line, here's an idea - `float`:

```
<div>
  <form name="frm1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="xxx"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit" style="float: left;">
  </form>
  <form name="frm2" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_reset" value="Reset" style="float: left;">
  </form>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

Note the line break with `clear: both;` at the end which makes sure that the next line will be really displayed on it's own line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="frm1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="xxx">       
    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit">     
</form>   
<form name="frm2" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

CSS

```
form, form input{
    float: left;
}
```

As seen here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWmnV/4/)

Obviously though this would have an effect on all form-input elements, but can be updated to include css classes.